# NServiceBus: WcfIntegration sample not working when hosting service on IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, nservicebus

I just downloaded a WcfIntegration sample from this link
https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/tree/master/IntegrationTests/WcfIntegration

I added a svc file in service project and hosted the service on IIS and its being accessed fine on browser.

After updating the endpoint information in client project i tried to run client but its not working.

I uncommented the endpoint information in service config

```
        <endpoint address="/cancelOrder"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="NServiceBus.IWcfService`2[[Messages.CancelOrder, Messages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Messages.ErrorCodes, Messages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]">
    </endpoint>
```

When using address="/cancelOrder" i am getting Object reference errror and with address="" i am facing mismatch error.

Please share if anyone have any idea how to achieve it.

Thanks,

Comment: I got the solution, its working now !! I have addded the global.asax file and write the code in Application_OnStart event                       'Bus = Configure.With()
           .DefineEndpointName("ServiceNameSpace").DefaultBuilder().UseTransport<Msmq>().PurgeOnStartup(true).UnicastBus() .CreateBus().Start(() => Configure.Instance .ForInstallationOn<Windows>() .Install());' code and its working fine now. Is there any other way where i can write the bus instance installisation code instaed of global.asax file, i have hosted the service on IIS with svc file.